# React native flatlist image list

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm looking for someone that could help me just images in a flatlist grid.
I was able to get it working  with text but not images in the assets folder.

I want to have separate images that will be stored in the assets folder to be in the boxes of the flatlist grid.

Please let me know if you need more information!

Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Image, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, FlatList, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { drawer } from '../navigation/AppNavigation';
import { hp, wp } from '../utils/responsiveScreen';

const dataList = [{ key: '1' }, { key: '2' }, { key: '3' }, { key: '4' }, { key: '5' },{ key: '6' },{ key: '6' },{ key: '6' }]


const numColums = 2

const WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width


const Main = () => {

  formatData = (data, numColums) =>{

    const totalRows = Math.floor(data.length / numColums)
    let totalLastRow = dataList.length - (totalRows * numColums)

    while(totalLastRow !== 0 && totalLastRow !== numColums){
      dataList.push({'key': 'blank', empty: true})
      totalLastRow++
    }
    return dataList

  }
  _renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {

    let {itemStyle, itemText} = styles

    if(item.empty){
      return <View style={[itemStyle]}/>
    }

    return (
      <View style={itemStyle}>
        <Text style={styles.itemText}>{item.key}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{ height: 50 }}
        onPress={() => drawer.current.open()}>
        <Image source={require('../assets/menu.png')} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Stars</Text>

      <FlatList
        data={this.formatData(dataList, numColums)}
        renderItem={this._renderItem}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        numColumns = {numColums}
      />

    </View>
  );
};
```

And here is the Style sheet:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    paddingTop: hp(7),
    paddingHorizontal: wp(6),
  },
  
  textStyle: {
    marginBottom: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 24,
    color: 'black',
  },
  image: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
    height: hp(40),
    width: hp(40),
    marginTop: hp(3),
  },

  itemStyle: {
    backgroundColor: 'pink',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    height: 150,
    flex: 1,
    margin:1,
    width: WIDTH / numColums
  },
  itemText: {
    fontSize: 50
  }
  
});
```

I have attached an image of what it looks like now:
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLnTO.jpg)

**UPDATE**

I have updated the datalist to this:

```
const dataList = [{ key: '1',image: required('../assets/backGround.png')}, { key: '2',image: required('../assets/backGround.png') }, { key: '3' ,image: required('../assets/backGround.png')}]
```

And the view to this:

```
  <View style={itemStyle}>
    {/* <Text style={styles.itemText}>{item.key}</Text> */}
    <Image
      style={styles.image}
      source={item.image}
    />
  </View>
```

and I now get the error:

```
TypeError: (0, _reactNative.required) is not a function. (In '(0, _reactNative.required)('../assets/backGround.png')', '(0, _reactNative.required)' is undefined)
```

Comment: You can render Image in your _renderItem function. before that you should add your images to your list data (dataList)

Comment: const dataList = [{ key: '1' , image: required('address_to_first_image')}, { key: '2', image: required('address_to_second_image') }]. In the _renderItem return <Image source={item.image} style={styles.image />

Comment: you're a gentleman, thank you!

Comment: @Majidlotfinia I have updated the code with a new issue as that has not fully worked, would you mind having another look please?

Comment: you made a typo, its ```require(..)``` not ```required(...)```

Comment: So silly! thank you!

Comment: yeah. it was a typo :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const dataList = [{ key: '1',image: required('../assets/backGround.png')}, { key: '2',image: required('../assets/backGround.png') }, { key: '3' ,image: required('../assets/backGround.png')}]
```

needs to be

```
const dataList = [{ key: '1',image: require('../assets/backGround.png')}, { key: '2',image: require('../assets/backGround.png') }, { key: '3' ,image: require('../assets/backGround.png')}]
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add require() to the source in the image tag